# Checking current_user is a post's author

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to limit editing capability to an article's author in my rails app.

In my controller I'm adding the user id as the author which works fine:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.author = current_user.id
  ...
 end
```

then checking it on the edit action:

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Whoa there amigo!' unless current_user.id == @article.author
end
```

Editing results in redirect every time.

(I'm not using Devise, CanCan or anything else at this point as this is the only functionality I need right now.)

**Update**

Based on comments, I updated my create method to:

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
```

and my edit method to:

```
def edit
  @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Whoa..' unless current_user.id.to_s == @article.user_id
```

This works but "current_user.id.to_s" seems a bit hacky for something that must be incredibly common.

Comment: That's because `@article.author` returns an author object, not an id, and so `@article.author == current_user.id` will never pass. Should be `@article.author == current_user`. But, you could simply find article via association (which will return 404 if not found) like this: `@article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])`. Same with create action: `@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)`

Comment: Using "@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)" in the create method results in this error "undefined method `articles' for #<User:0x007f9e97476f48>"

Comment: That was assuming you had your relationships setup correctly. If a user has many articles, then you should have `has_many :articles` in your `User` model.

Comment: Oops. Got it. Now I'm creating the article with `@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)` and using user_id instead of author. Much nicer...  but `@article.author == current_user` still returns false. I do a binding.pry and `current_user` and `@article.user_id` each return "1" ... but the are not the same.  hmmmm.

Comment: Naturally "current_user.id.to_s == @article.user_id" returns true, but it doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: `current_user` should return a `User` object, not the `id`. When you compare two objects, Rails automatically extracts the ids in the comparison. What does `@article.author.id` return?

Answer (score 0):

In create action:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.author = current_user
  ...
end
```

And in edit change the condition to:

```
unless current_user == @article.author
```

This way you compare user objects and not user objects with ids.

Comment: Sorry. Doesn't work. See my comment above. I'm overlooking something obvious I'm sure.